# Can't shrink Ubuntu partition Gparted ERROR (238277632K 00:00:05)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, error-handling

I am using 'Gparted live USB' and I receive the error log (below) when I try and shrink my Ubuntu partition. I don't know what the error means or what is causing it.

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 installed on the same machine (Dell Inspiron 3521 [specs](http://www.cnet.com/products/dell-inspiron-3521-15-6-pentium-2127u-4-gb-ram-500-gb-hdd-english-us/specs/)). When I first installed, I formatted a black space of roughly 40GB on my internal HDD (Using Windows disk management) and installed Ubuntu on that. Ubuntu installer automatically divided that into roughly 36GB OS partition and 3.88GB SWAP space. Since then I have needed more space on Ubuntu so I shrank my Windows partition (`dev/sda5`) and extended my Ubuntu partition (`dev/sda9`) (See screen-shot link below). Did this using Gparted live USB boot and it all worked fine. Gparted version: `gparted-live-0.26.0-2-i686.ios`

Please see partitions here (Gparted screen-shot)

[image]

Now I want to create more SWAP space since I could actually do with about 8GB SWAP so I want to shrink Ubuntu (`dev/sda9`) and then expand SWAP (`dev/sda10`). There is definitely enough free space on `dev/sda9` (I am only trying to shrink by 4.02GB and there is 208.93GB available). But when trying to shrink Ubuntu I get this ERROR:

```
shrink file system  00:00:05    ( ERROR )
resize2fs -p /dev/sda9 238277632K  00:00:05    ( ERROR )
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/sda9 to 59569408 (4k) blocks.
Begin pass 3 (max = 1851)
Scanning inode table X---------------------------------------
resize2fs 1.43-WIP (15-Mar-2016)
```

Any help appreciated.

I am a bit of a new-be to Ubuntu (5 days now) so I may have easily overlooked something obvious.

Thanks!

**Full Gparted log:**

```
GParted 0.26.0 --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2

Shrink /dev/sda9 from 231.26 GiB to 227.24 GiB  00:00:25    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda9  00:00:04    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda9 (partition)
start: 452954112
end: 937947135
size: 484993024 (231.26 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sda9 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:16    ( SUCCESS )

e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 /dev/sda9  00:00:16    ( SUCCESS )

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure 
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity 
Pass 4: Checking reference counts 
Pass 5: Checking group summary information 

438487 inodes used (2.90%, out of 15133776)
671 non-contiguous files (0.2%)
284 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
# of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
Extent depth histogram: 387176/78
5846728 blocks used (9.64%, out of 60624128)
0 bad blocks
1 large file

324904 regular files
45109 directories
55 character device files
25 block device files
0 fifos
35029 links
68384 symbolic links (51144 fast symbolic links)
1 socket
------------
473507 files
e2fsck 1.43-WIP (15-Mar-2016)
shrink file system  00:00:05    ( ERROR )

resize2fs -p /dev/sda9 238277632K  00:00:05    ( ERROR )

Resizing the filesystem on /dev/sda9 to 59569408 (4k) blocks.
Begin pass 3 (max = 1851)
Scanning inode table X---------------------------------------
resize2fs 1.43-WIP (15-Mar-2016)
```

Comment: The easy way : Create a swap file inside Ubuntu ...  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq → →  "Four-step Process to Add Swap File" -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered on the GParted Forum.  See [Can't shrink partition - ERROR 238277632K 00:00:05](http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=17558).

The TL;DR is to use live media with e2fsprogs < 1.43 such as [GParted Live 0.25.0-3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.25.0-3/) in the meantime until the base issues can be addressed.